# parse a php file with temp variable

Tags: php, if-statement

I have a php file like this

```
if ($a=='number1'){
  $b=2;
  $c=3;
}

elseif ($a=='letterA'){
  $b=33;
  $c=44;
}
  elseif ($a=='something'){
  $b=222;
  $c=3333;
}
```

Now I want to parse this file and get values "temporarily" for $b and $c. It is to say I need to , set $a variable and get the results for $b and $c

in other words In a php file i need to temporarily set

```
$a='number1';
```

so I can extrapolate values of $b and $c without having to actually load the page that now sets the variable.

from within the same file I need to generate

```
Name: 'number1'; this is setting the $a value
address: '$b'; // corresponding to 'number1 or $a variable
phone: '$c';  // corresponding to 'number1 or $a variable
```

and

```
Name: 'letterA'; this is setting the $a value
address: '$b'; // corresponding to letterA or $a variable
phone: '$c';  // corresponding to letterA or $a variable
```

seems simple enough but I am stuck

thanks in advance

Mark

Comment: Have you considered putting your comparison code in a function?

Comment: I suppose that muight be the solution of only I knew how.

Comment: make array `[ [ number1 => [a=>1, b=>2]], [ numberA => [a=>3, b=>4]],]` and then get `$array['numberA']['a']`...

Comment: The problem with this solution is that I need this all to be dynamic, I need to fetch the variables relevant in each if / elseif. If I can fetch the variables relevant to each if/ elseif. There would be no reason for the array, unless I am missing something